# Dictionary of lists: writing lists (with tab separated items) to different files for each key (Python)

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains lists; the keys are based on the first item in each list. Using a fun random data set, the dictionary was constructed as follows:

```
import collections

rand_ls = [["A","bb","cc"],["B","dd","ee"],["A","ff","gg"],["B","hh","ii"]]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for item in rand_ls:
    d[item[0]].append(item)

print(dict(d))
    # {'A': [['A', 'bb', 'cc'], ['A', 'ff', 'gg']], 'B': [['B', 'dd', 'ee'], ['B', 'hh', 'ii']]}
```

I want to write the lists held in each key into separate .csv files, one for each key. The closest solution I have found was detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956523/write-key-to-separate-csv-based-on-value-in-dictionary), but I can't get it to work. The format I am after:

```
letterA.csv
    A    bb    cc
    A    ff    gg

letterB.csv
    B    dd    ee
    B    hh    ii
```

NOTE: **letter{}.csv** is the unique file for each key; each list (within each key) is on a separate line, and each item within a list is separated by a tab.

The code I have is this:

```
for key,lists in d.items():
    with open("letter{}.csv".format(key), "w") as f:
       f.writelines(lists, delimiter='\t')
```

It keeps throwing up the error: **"TypeError: writelines() takes no keyword arguments"**. I've done some reading and I know writelines() takes a sequence of strings, so not quite sure what is missing.

Based on what I have read elsewhere, the code **open("letter{}.csv".format(key), "w")** should create a unique file for each key, and the subsequent line should direct the lists to be written to the appropriate file.

Comment: I guess the `writelines()` method is expecting string instead of list, for converting list to string you can use `"\t".join(lst)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal `file.write` takes no keywords args, you are probably getting confused with and should should use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) which does take the `delimiter` argument, iterating over `d.items`, passing the `k` key to `str.format` and the list of lists to `csv.writer.writerows`.

```
import csv

for k, rows in d.items():
    with open("letter_{}.csv".format(k), "w") as out:
        wr = csv.writer(out,delimiter='\t')
        wr.writerows(rows)
```

LetterA.csv:

```
A   bb  cc
A   ff  gg
```

LetterB.csv:

```
B   dd  ee
B   hh  ii
```

Comment: Cheers @Padraic! Works a charms. :D

Comment: No prob. The csv module is ideal for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error that you're receiving: `writelines() takes no keyword arguments`. Do you see keyword arguments in your call to `writelines`?

You need to join your strings together with `\t` before passing them to `writelines`.

Answer (score 1):

[io.IOBase.writelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines):

> Write a list of lines to the stream. Line separators are not added, so it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a line separator at the end.

```
f.writelines(["{}\n".format('\t'.join(list_)) for list_ in lists])
```

Comment: You're welcome @jat but please make sure you close this question by accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for key,lists in d.items():
    with open("letter{}.csv".format(key), "w") as f:
       f.write('\t'.join(lists))
```

As the error message you are getting indicates, `writelines` does not take keyword arguments (such as `delimiter`). Since you are not writing a list to the file, but instead a string created from a list joined by a tab character, you don't even need `writelines`.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is telling you that it doesn't accept keyword arguments, so if you jump to your `writelines()` call, the first issue is that you're passing it a keyword param when it can't accept it. Specfically: `f.writelines(lists,`**delimiter='\t'**)

`writelines` will accept a list of strings to be written to the file but you'll need to deal with all the formatting yourself if you go this route. If you wanted that I suspect you want:

```
for key,lists in d.items():
    with open("letter{}.csv".format(key), "w") as f:
       f.writelines('\n'.join(['\t'.join(x) for x in l]))
```

Since you have a list of lists, the inner list comprehension just glues things within each list by tabs, and then the outer loop glues all of those together with end of line characters.

However just judging from the pattern and the question tags - have you considered using the CSV module, and it's associated writer method? (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: `f.writelines` expects a list of lines.

Comment: @Sir_FZ f.writelines expects to get a list of things to write to a file, which it calls a 'line'. Sure, me calling it a string is probably a bit glib, but in OP's case it's a tab-delimited, newline terminated string is it not?

Comment: yes you're right but since the documentation states it accepts a **list** of lines then it makes more sense to pass a list instead of a string, for the sake of compatibility.

Comment: @Sir_FZ Yep, fair enough, my bad on bashing something together roughly. I'd also pass in a list of things but I'd also just go straight for the CSV module since it's a better fit for the problem.